# How to find an item in a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, function, methods

There is a nested list A:

```
A =  [[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 1, 9], [-3, 0, 7], [-4, 0, 5]]
```

How can I check to see if any of the items in A start with -1 ([-1, :, :]) and if yes, what is its index using a single function or method and not loops?

Comment: Explain why you can't use a loop.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have used this loop: **counter = 0 for d in range(len(A)): if counter == 0: if len(A[d]) != 0: if A[d][0] == -1: index = d counter = 1** and when A becomes large, the code gets very slow.

Answer (score 1):

finding all the indices without a loop is hard, I'm not aware of a way to do this other than numpy's `where()` function like this

```
import numpy as np

a = [[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 1, 9], [-3, 0, 7], [-4, 0, 5]]
search_value = -1

def find_indices(lst):
    np_array = np.array(lst)
    # Find indices where the first column is -1
    indices = np.where(np_array[:, 0] == search_value)[0]
    return indices

# Usage
indices= find_indices(a)
print(indices)  # Output: [0 3]
```

although numpy may use loops under the hood of the `where()` function, that's beyond my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, use a one-liner with a `list comprehension` and the `next()` function.

```
index = next((i for i, sublist in enumerate(A) if sublist[0] == -1), None)
print(f"Index: {index}" if index is not None else "No items")
```

or Something like this by using if else after `enumerate()`

```
A = [[-1, 0, 1], [-2, 1, 9], [-3, 0, 7], [-4, 0, 5]]

matching_indices = [index for index, sublist in enumerate(A) if sublist[0] == -1]

if matching_indices:
    print("Found at indices:", matching_indices)
else:
    print("No items found.")
```

Comment: This is what ChatGPT gave me as well. I wanted something simpler using "in" and index() maybe? what if there were more nests inside the list?

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 does this code look for -1 anywhere or just a sublist which starts with -1?

Comment: @Sherwin can you give the recreatable scenario where there are  more nests inside the list()

Comment: @Sherwin  I can think of nested lists within them and I can suggest use recusrsive function with the same logic checking for input as instance of list

Comment: @Sherwin: There's no built-in functionality for what you're going for aside from listcomps and genexprs. `list.index` only searches for a specific value, not a portion of a value. `in` is similar. If listcomp/genexpr is not an option, it's `numpy` or nothing.

Comment: `for index, sublist in enumerate(A)` this is certainly a loop, which they said they didn't want.